# Signature for casting associated type

Tags: rust

I have a trait with an associated type, and two impls of the trait on structs A and B. I want to define a function that takes a generic bounded by my trait and returns the same root type, but a different inner type. I need it to be impossible to change the root type with the function. In the real-world context, I could make use of the change in the inner type in the surrounding code with a trait bound that translates between the two associated types.

```rust
trait ExampleTrait {
    type Associated;
    fn new() -> Self;
}
struct A<T> {phantom_a: PhantomData<T>}
struct B<T> {phantom_b: PhantomData<T>}
impl<T> ExampleTrait for A<T> { type Associated = T; fn new() -> Self {A {phantom_a: PhantomData}} }
impl<T> ExampleTrait for B<T> { type Associated = T; fn new() -> Self {B {phantom_b: PhantomData}} }

fn cast_associated_type<TI: ExampleTrait, TO: ExampleTrait>(_input: TI) -> TO {
    TO::new()
}

fn main() {
    // expected behavior
    let _a: A<f64> = cast_associated_type(A::<u32>::new());
    // poor behavior (origin is allowed to change)
    let _b: B<u32> = cast_associated_type(A::<u32>::new());
}
```

Is this restriction possible to express in the rust type system? Thank you.

Comment: *"I need it to be impossible to change the root type with the function"* - `A<u32>` is a different type than `A<f64>` as far as Rust is concerned. You'd need the function to be generic over a generic type, which AFAIK there's no support for.

Comment: This makes sense. I think I was thrown off by the associated type. If you strip out the associated type, the higher kinded type issue you pointed is more obvious.